# Concerning Magenta 1.9. - “Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page“

Tags: forms, magento, key, magento-1.9

I have a problem with the Safari browser complaining about unsecure transfer when adding products to the basket and fails. So, I sat the unsecure transfer to https in configurations. That helped for Safari but now I can’t log in to the Magento admin. I get: *“Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page“*.

In phpMyAdmin > core_config_data I changed the unsecure transfer back to http. That didn’t help so I deleted the whole site from the server and uploaded a one-week old backup, but I still got the same error. Finally, I have deleted the backup and uploaded the original. And of course, still have the error.

I have emptied var/session, var/cache and var/reports and flushed my own cache and deleted cookies.
I have found technical solutions as https://www.tigren.com/magento-error-invalid-form-key/, but I’m a novice and on top of that not a programmer.

Now, when I try to address the site via phpMyAdmin I get *“mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)”*.

When everything else fails for me I can e-mail the host company to work on the server. But what to write?

Could a professional please walk me through a solution?

Comment: Hi Tony I have check this post on freelance platform

Comment: Thank you Vasim but another freelancer is working on it.

Comment: I can help you Tony if you can share some details

Comment: Thank you Vasim Shaikh but another freelancer is working on it.